# Removing .php extensions from files in htdocs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my project in my `htdocs` folder where my main file is `index.php`. I have tried multiple time to remove the `.php` extension when the file is opened in the browser, using the `.htaccess` file with the following lines without luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

The extension remains. Is it because the link in my browser is

```
file:///C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/htdocs/Cipcpr/index.php
```

and not

```
localhost/...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# remove php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite with php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project doesn't need to remove extensions dynamically, you can manually set the `RewriteRules` for every file. Here is the code for your index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

when you now type /index it will reference to /index.php file.

To add other file (let's say login.php) you can just copy last RewriteRule and rewrite the indexes.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add .htaccess file to the root folder of your site(for example, /home/domains/domain.com/htdocs/) with following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```