# How to write .htaccess to hide page extensions even after a link is clicked?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, xampp

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

In the browser, when I goto, localhost/fest/, the index.php loads automatically and the URL in the browser stays localhost/fest/.

But when I click any link in index.php, say for example, Two, URL in the browser turns to localhost/fest/two.php

How can I hide the URL even after user clicking a link. I am using xampp 3.2.2, Apache 2.4, PHP Version 5.x.x. OverRide is allowed.

Comment: You cant Hide the URL exactly, but you can make what's known as SEO links where your link of http://mywebsite.com/products?id=5 would be http://mywebsite.com/products/5 instead. -- if you really wish to "hide" the URL, you're going to have to use some sort of php include() to include the pages you want from the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing .php extensions from files in htdocs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498430/removing-php-extensions-from-files-in-htdocs)